# Gaps after unstacking columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe that has model response of each model in its dedicated column:

[image]

The code I tried is following:

```html
df.groupby('Model')['Model_Response']
df=df.unstack(0).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

But it gives me response as follows:

[image]

How can this be fixed to eliminate the empty spaces?

Comment: Use `df.pivot(index='GroundTruth', columns='Model', values='Model_Response')`

Comment: @jezrael it says `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='GroundTruth', columns='Model', values='Model_Response', aggfunc=','.join)`

Comment: @jezrael, it worked,  thanks. if it was added as an answer, I would have accepted it but apparently the question is closed

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate, so closed. No possible add answer.